# angularJS: How to conditionnaly display an element outside of ng-view?

Tags: angularjs

Considering the following angular 1.X index.html file:

```
<div ng-app="app" class="hero-unit">
    <a ng-show="!isHomePage" href="#!/home">Home</a>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to display the element `<a ng-show="!isHomePage" href="#!/home">Home</a>` only when the location is not the home page?
How should I proceed? Should I map this element on a dedicated controller as `mainController`? Is that a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ways to achieve this :**

- You can create a **`parent level controller(outside ng-view)`** in the application and then check the current route and based on that implement the condition.

  Home

To get the current path you can use :

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (e, current, pre) {
        console.log(current.originalPath); // Do not use $$route here it is private
    });
});
```

**`OR`**

`$location.path()`

- You can use **`$scope.$emit`** if you want to do it based on any event in the view.`$emit` will help in communication between child to parent.
- You can create an `angular service` through that you can pass the current state of the application and based on that implement the condition.

Comment: inside the listener you give, I add ` $rootScope.showButton = current.originalPath.indexOf("home") !== -1 ? false : true;
` but in the parent level controller div,  `{{showButton}}` is null. Could you give a full example please with html and js?

Comment: What is `current.originalPath` ?

Comment: I found, it was a template engine conflict! The old app original template engine was trying to evaluate angular expression between curly braces! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `ng-app` to the body level, and then use a service in the $rootScope to detect if it's the home page or not - I do this in some of my apps.

e.g.

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div class="hero-unit">
<a ng-show="!NavigationService.isHomePage()" href="#!/home">Home</a>
<input id="token" type="hidden" value="{{token}}">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Then in your app.js run method, set the `NavigationService` to the rootScope,

e.g.

`$rootScope.NavigationService = NavigationService;`

Answer (score 0):

You can check current url:
See this example from:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

```
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <div class="view-animate-container">
      <div ng-view class="view-animate"></div>
   </div>
    <hr />

  $location.path() = {{main.$location.path()}}
  $route.current.templateUrl = {{main.$route.current.templateUrl}}
  $route.current.params = {{main.$route.current.params}}
  $routeParams = {{main.$routeParams}}
 </div>
```